# Gridview not showing in web site but showing in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web site that uses .net framework and I have a table that pulls data from a db to display on the site. I have the connection to the db, the data is being pulled and when I use the localhost browser it shows perfect but when I use the site on the server it gives me an error or shows nothing. When I get an error it is the web.config custom errors needs to me turned off. What would stop the table from showing on the server but showing on the localhost?

Comment: Could you post the error? so we can try to help?

Comment: There is no way for us to help you, without knowing what the error is. Change the web.config section as instructed in the error screen so it'll give you full details. Then post the error here, along with the relevant source code, and then we can help.

Comment: without using my psychic powers to obtain your code (which I promised my girlfriend I wouldn't use again after *the incident*) I can't help

Comment: WTF is upvoting this!?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your web server does not have access to the data and is throwing up an error, but the web.config is preventing the actually error, instead throwing a generic error page.

You need to update your web.config to have

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Whilst this response won't solve the problem, it will tell you what the underlying error is and you can then take appropriate action.

Comment: While this does not solve the ultimate problem the OP has, it does solve the only problem that OP stated coherently, so +1.